# Eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix with entries in (-1,1)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $\textbf{M}=(m_{ij})$ be a positive definite square matrix of order $k$, in which $m_{11}=1$ and, $m_{ij}\in(-1,1)$ for $i,j=1,2,\ldots,k$ ($i\ne1$ $\&$ $j\ne1$).

Is there any knowledge about the eigenvalues of a matrix such as $\textbf{M}$?

I think that $\textbf{M}$ has an eigenvalue bigger than $1$, and the remaining ones are less than $1$, but I do not know if such a result can be proved (if it holds).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem this may help

Comment: The largest eigenvalue is $\ge1$, not $>1$, attained for $M=id$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Schur-Horn Theorem if $M$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric real matrix (not necessarily positive definite) whose diagonal entries satisfy $m_{11}\geq...\geq m_{nn}$ then for all $1\leq k\leq n$
$$
(*)\qquad\sum_{i=1}^k m_{ii}\leq \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i
$$
where $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $M$.

In the situation of the question, we can assume up to conjugating by a permutation matrix, that $M$ has diagonal entries satisfying
$$
m_{11}=1\geq...\geq m_{nn}\geq -1.
$$
Then $(*)$ with $k=1$ gives $1\leq\lambda_1$. So there is indeed an eigenvalue $\geq 1$.

However the matrix
$$
M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is a positive-definite symmetric matrix with entries in $(-1,1)$ with eigenvalues
$$
\left\{\frac{5}{4},\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{8} ,\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{8}\right\}
$$
and the first two eigenvalues are larger than $1$.

EDIT: There is an easier alternative to see that there exists at least one eigenvalue $\geq 1$. Indeed, that the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of a real symmetric matrix is
$$
\lambda_1=\sup_{|x|=1}x^\top Mx.
$$
Taking $x=(1,0,...,0)$ we see that if $m_{11}=1$, then $\lambda_1\geq 1$.

Comment: last line: $\lambda_1\ge1$ can be concluded only (take $M=I_3$)

Comment: Yes sure, I will edit :)